# TFS 2015 - Description field's rich text controls

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, richtext, field-description

Hopefully this is a simple question... is it possible to access the same rich text formatting options as seen within Visual Studio 2015, within TFS 2015 ?

**VS 2015** 
 
[image]

**TFS 2015** 
[image]

---

XML from the above TFS WIT : 
`<Tab Label="Description"> <Control FieldName="System.Description" Type="HtmlFieldControl" Dock="Fill" LabelPosition="Top" /> </Tab>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Description field of work item in VS and Web Access use the same XML file, but the rich text formatting options are not controlled by the XML file.

Currently, there is no option to change the rich text formatting options. I have created a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it. Microsoft Product Team will evaluate it carefully:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16434553-tfs-web-access-has-the-same-rich-text-formatting-o

Comment: Thanks! I voted on the provided link ... will hope for the best now :)

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary workaround, you can copy the text to Word, apply the rich formatting there and copy it back to TFS.